# Which type of specialist should we see for bleeding and possible liver damage after alcohol withdrawal?

Tags: alcohol, liver, bleeding, bloated-bloating, alcohol-withdrawal

My father (aged 53) has stopped drinking alcohol  since January and due to this he has a low bp 110/60, when he goes to the toilet bleeding there is blood in the urine, hemoglobin is 6, stomach is full and tight (seems like bloating), he sleeps for almost 24 hours. Which type of specialist is suitable for such a condition? (We are based in India).

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). I have rephrased your question slightly to make it more clear, I hope that you don't mind. You have the option to roll-back to a previous version if you click the edit history (in blue, above my name).

Comment: He should go to the ER very soon. A hemoglobin of 6 can be fatally low, especially since he's still bleeding.  The stomach fullness is possibly ascites, the excess sleeping is possibly encephalopathy, the bleeding could be kidney failure or rectal bleeding - - there is no way to tell without an evaluation.  But these are bad signs. He may sooner or later want to see a hepatologist (liver doctor), assuming his drinking was long-term, as he might have cirrhosis.  But at the moment getting emergent care may be an issue of life or death. Ask the ER doctor what specialist to see.

Comment: Emergency medicine. He is critically ill and needs to be in a hospital right now.